# What is the largest value a quotient can be?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

This question is from a Calculus textbook. It goes as follows: if we have the expression $a^2k\over (1 + akt)$, where $a, k$ are constants and $t$ is a real variable; what is the largest value the expression can be, and at what $t$? I first thought that this is absurd, for the largest value can be infinitely great if we make the numerator infinitely small. Hence I equated $1 + akt$ to $0$ and we get $t = $$-1\over ak$. Though, the book follows something different. The author equates $1 + akt$ to $1$ and gets $t = 0$. I do not at all understand why this was done. Could someone explain the reason? Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's dangerous to use intuition on a problem like this. The a,k also appear in the numerator, so making the denominator small might affect the numerator also, and thus fail to make the whole fraction large as possible. Better to leave the constants in, and do usual max via derivatives etc.

Comment: By the way. does your calc book say anything at all about the values of a and k? e.g are they positive?

Comment: To elucidate, this is actually a result the book gets from a chemistry problem. $a$ is the molar mass, so it obviously must be positive. $t$ is for time. $k$ is just a proportionality constant, and it is not given whether it is positive or negative. Could you explain why the denominator was equated to $1$. Also, the theory of local maxima and minima hasn't been developed at this point in the book, so I don't believe it expects the reader to use it.

Comment: Let's assume $k>0$, as otherwise we are going to run into the same problem of having $0$ on the denominator. Then, since this function is monotonically decreasing in $t$, we therefore want to take the minimal value of $t$. Obviously, we must have $t\ge 0$, because $t$ is representative of time, and we can't have negative time.

Comment: @Cameron, Whether we can have "negative time" is going to depend on the situation being described. It is quite common to set the zero point of time at some significant event, and consider what happens around that time, both before and after. But otherwise, you are correct. Generally equations are written so that the proportionality constants are positive, so that is a good assumption here. And I would guess in this case that the set up of the problem only makes sense for positive times. This results in $t \ge 0$ and $t=0$ giving the maximum.